# Getting height of an element inside expanding grid

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the height of img element inside the expanding grid. I am using the following jQuery code to grab the height of the element with class name ".entry-image" but unfortunately it is only grabbing the height when I am closing the expanding grid. I want to grab it as soon as I open the expanding grid and output in my console.

**jQuery**

```
$('.links a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $height = $('.expanding-container .entry-image').outerHeight();
    console.log($height);
});
```

At first when I am clicking to open the grid, console is showing null value, but whenever I am closing it, console is showing the right value which is 372. Can anyone help me out here please?

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/audhit/pen/ZKxdqP)

Comment: The container is set to `display:none` - so it and all of its descendants are not even rendered, and therefor you can not get any measurements either. You need to wait until the display has been toggled before you can do that.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe , but my purpose is to assign this extracted height to the adjacent elements of the grid so that all images in my grid have the same height. So, if I wait for the image to render then my purpose wont be served! Wondering is there any cool solution for this :(

Comment: If you only need the intrinsic image dimensions, you could simply create an image object in JS, and read the height in the load handler. But if you need the height of the image it has when all formatting in the current context is applied (like responsive image styles that affect the height), then you need to get this rendered first, before you can access the actual height. A solution (although not a very nice one) could be to create a clone of the relevant container element, and have that rendered somewhere outside the viewport (absolute positioning, top/left with large negative values).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try your suggestions,cheers